# how to open a modal and autoclose after 3 seconds

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a bootstrap modal dialog box that I want to show when I click a link, then after 3 seconds it will disappears, so how can I adjust this following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('.popup-modal').magnificPopup({
          type: 'inline',
          preloader: false,
          focus: '#username',
          modal: true
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.popup-modal-dismiss', function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.magnificPopup.close();
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try setting a timeout...

Comment: To some search online.. You will get scripts.. Ask here only if you got stuck somewhere..

Comment: look for javascript timers - that will run the timer and 'click' for you.  You are close, but you do need to try some things first, not just ask someone to write the code for you.

Comment: thanks all, I have tried with setTimeout but I am not sure where to to insert the function correctly